# telepresence agent install timed out

Tags: intercept, telepresence

Have a k8s cluster in gcloud, in which running a few http applications.

Used to debug with telepresence from localhost without issue.

But today it always hit agent `install time out` error.

kubectl to the cluster, no issue.

```
telepresence connect
Launching Telepresence Root Daemon
Need root privileges to run: /usr/local/bin/telepresence daemon-foreground /Users/xxx/Library/Logs/telepresence '/Users/xxx/Library/Application Support/telepresence' ''
Password:
Launching Telepresence User Daemon
Connected to context my-cluster (https://xx.xxx.xxx.x)

telepresence intercept xxx-service --env-json /tmp/xxx-service.json
telepresence: error: Intercept: Failed to establish intercept: the agent install timed out. The current timeout 2m0s can be configured as "timeouts.agentInstall" in "/Users/xxx/Library/Application Support/telepresence/config.yml"
```

some logs from telepresence

```
2021/09/01 12:24:04.4264 info    connector : --- (from pkg/client/connector/command.go:329)
2021/09/01 12:24:04.4272 info    connector : Telepresence Connector v2.4.1 (api v3) starting... (from pkg/client/connector/command.go:330)
2021/09/01 12:24:04.4272 info    connector : PID is 956 (from pkg/client/connector/command.go:331)
2021/09/01 12:24:04.4272 info    connector :  (from pkg/client/connector/command.go:332)
2021/09/01 12:24:04.4276 info    connector/server-grpc : gRPC server started (from pkg/client/connector/command.go:361)
2021/09/01 12:24:04.6103 info    connector/background-init : Connecting to daemon... (from pkg/client/connector/command.go:165)
2021/09/01 12:24:04.6109 info    connector/background-init : Connecting to k8s cluster... (from pkg/client/connector/command.go:179)
2021/09/01 12:24:04.6544 info    connector/background-init : Server version v1.18.20-gke.901 (from pkg/client/connector/userd_k8s/k8s_cluster.go:87)
2021/09/01 12:24:04.6554 info    connector/background-init : Context: my-cluster (from pkg/client/connector/userd_k8s/k8s_cluster.go:276)
2021/09/01 12:24:04.6560 info    connector/background-init : Server: https://xx.xxx.xxx.x (from pkg/client/connector/userd_k8s/k8s_cluster.go:277)
2021/09/01 12:24:04.6561 info    connector/background-init : Connected to context my-cluster (https://xx.xxx.xxx.x) (from pkg/client/connector/command.go:204)
2021/09/01 12:24:04.8000 info    connector/background-init : Connecting to traffic manager... (from pkg/client/connector/command.go:220)
2021/09/01 12:24:04 Patching synced Namespace 132db4b7-8e18-11ea-b69f-42010a940011
2021/09/01 12:24:04.8006 info    connector/background-init : Waiting for TrafficManager to connect (from pkg/client/connector/command.go:242)
2021/09/01 12:24:04.8009 debug   connector/background-k8swatch/namespaces : posting search paths [ambassador default istio-system kafka kube-node-lease kube-public kube-system minio shift] (from pkg/client/connector/userd_k8s/outbound.go:175)
2021/09/01 12:24:04.8649 debug   connector/background-manager : Traffic Manager release was found to be in status deployed (from pkg/install/helm/release.go:46)
2021/09/01 12:24:04.8653 info    connector/background-manager : Existing Traffic Manager not owned by cli or does not need upgrade, will not modify (from pkg/install/helm/install.go:160)
2021/09/01 12:24:04.8673 debug   connector/background-manager : k8sPortForwardDialer.Dial(ctx, "svc/traffic-manager.ambassador:8081") (from pkg/dnet/kpfconn.go:82)
2021/09/01 12:24:04.8677 debug   connector/background-manager : kates.Get(svc traffic-manager.ambassador) (from pkg/dnet/kpfconn.go:127)
2021/09/01 12:24:04.9490 debug   connector/background-manager : k8sPortForwardDialer.dial(ctx, traffic-manager-b78b667d5-kvbn2.ambassador, 8081) (from pkg/dnet/kpfconn.go:228)
2021/09/01 12:24:04.9491 debug   connector/background-manager : k8sPortForwardDialer.spdyDial(ctx, Pod./traffic-manager-b78b667d5-kvbn2.ambassador) (from pkg/dnet/kpfconn.go:209)
2021/09/01 12:24:05.1013 debug   connector/background-manager/intercept-port-forward : posting search paths [ambassador default istio-system kafka kube-node-lease kube-public kube-system minio shift] (from pkg/client/connector/userd_k8s/outbound.go:175)
2021/09/01 12:25:09.8625 debug   connector/server-grpc/conn=3/CreateIntercept-5 : Deployment xxx-service already has an installed and up-to-date agent (from pkg/client/connector/userd_trafficmgr/install.go:248)
2021/09/01 12:25:09.8970 info    connector/server-grpc/conn=3/CreateIntercept-5 : Waiting for agent for Deployment xxx-service (from pkg/client/connector/userd_trafficmgr/agents.go:110)
2021/09/01 12:27:09.9017 error   connector/server-grpc/conn=3/CreateIntercept-5 : the agent install timed out.  The current timeout 2m0s can be configured as "timeouts.agentInstall" in "/Users/jun/Library/Application Support/telepresence/config.yml" (from pkg/client/connector/userd_trafficmgr/agents.go:113)
2021/09/01 12:29:04 Patching synced Namespace 132db4b7-8e18-11ea-b69f-42010a940011
2021/09/01 12:47:21.4372 debug   connector/server-grpc/conn=4/CreateIntercept-8 : Deployment xxx-service already has an installed and up-to-date agent (from pkg/client/connector/userd_trafficmgr/install.go:248)
2021/09/01 12:47:21.4727 info    connector/server-grpc/conn=4/CreateIntercept-8 : Waiting for agent for Deployment xxx-service (from pkg/client/connector/userd_trafficmgr/agents.go:110)
2021/09/01 12:49:04 Patching synced Namespace 132db4b7-8e18-11ea-b69f-42010a940011
2021/09/01 12:49:21.4784 error   connector/server-grpc/conn=4/CreateIntercept-8 : the agent install timed out.  The current timeout 2m0s can be configured as "timeouts.agentInstall" in "/Users/jun/Library/Application Support/telepresence/config.yml" (from pkg/client/connector/userd_trafficmgr/agents.go:113)
```

My internet speed is quite fast, both download and upload speed is > 50mbps.

Any clue?

Comment: Looking for answers too. My telepresence just stopped working after upgrading to MacOS `Monterey 12.5 (21G72)`

Comment: same here `DeadlineExceeded desc = request timed out while waiting for agent`